# Magento XML problem

Tags: xml, themes, magento

I'm developing my first Magento Theme, but for a testing reason, I had to re-install the entire environment.
Obviously first of deleting my previous installation, I've copied the folders of my theme.
After reinstallation I've put the theme's folders in theirs right place, but now nothing seems to work.. The system completely ignores my xml files: doesn't load the right stylesheet and the layout changes that I've made previously.
Before the re-installation the theme worked well.. 
The cache is disabled.. some advices?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the contents of the `var/cache/` directory.

Comment: I've remade the theme, and I solved the major problems, but is still not working very well... the getSkinUrl() function retrieve a wrong url (the path of modern theme)... in the cms page, I setted the right design and theme, and it works well; but in the other sections the path is wrong..
Take a look at: 
www.fomal.eu (right) and www.fomal.eu/customer/account/login/ (wrong) ...
How can I fix this?
I followed the magento designer guide, then I have only 1 local.xml file and only the needed phtml files into my folder..

Comment: I solved it :) and I think can be useful for other with the same problem:
I deleted the content of the folder /var/cache and then I replaced the 'getSkinUrl()/image_name.png '
with 
'getSkinUrl('image_name.png')'
for all the images in the phtml files..